# Duda con un ciclo for, que no concatena todos los valores de los índices

Tags: java, netbeans

¿Alguien sabe por qué no me muestra todos los números del 0 al 10 en el label?

```
for(int contador = 0;contador <=10;contador++)
    lblTime.setText(""+contador);
```

En cambio, sólo me muestra el número 10 (sin los anteriores).

Si cambio el label por un JOptionPane, ahí sí me los muestra del 0 al 10.

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar un poco más tu problema? ¿Te da algún error o simplemente no te los muestra?

Comment: perdon se me olvido comentar que solo me muestra el numero 10.

Comment: Hola @cesarfire. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Si alguna de las respuestas ayudó a solucionar el problema de tu pregunta, por favor considera [aceptarla](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) haciendo click en el **✔️**, que está bajo las flechas de votación, a la izquierda de la respuesta  (no se te descuenta nada por eso -todo lo contrario, ambos se benefician).

Comment: @Mariano: ¿Cómo hicistes para incluir el icono de la respuesta aceptada en tu comentario?

Comment: @sstan es [un caracter Unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2714/index.htm)  .. Se puede ⎘ copiar y  pegar, usar una  extensión de Chrome, o buscar algunos usados comúnmente http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html .... ¿ǝpoɔᴉu∩? 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que estás sobreescribiendo todo el rato el valor del texto de la etiqueta.

Para mostrar todos los números podrías almacenarlos en un `String` y luego imprimirlos en la label. Ten en cuenta que la asignación del texto final a la etiqueta la tendrás que realizar una vez terminado el bucle ya que si no va a realizar 10 inserciones en la etiqueta sobreescribiendo en cada una de las iteraciones el número anterior y solamente dejando el último valor.

Este sería tu código corregido:

```
String numeros = "";

for(int contador = 0;contador <=10;contador++){
    numeros = numeros + " " + contador;
}
lblTime.setText(numeros);
```

Comment: muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Aqui da igual, pero por buena costumbre sobre rendimientos, no acumular strings dentro de bucles, sino usar la clase StringBuilder:

```
StringBuilder numeros = new StringBuilder();

for(int contador = 0;contador <=10;contador++) {
    if (contador > 0)
        numeros.append(" ");
    numeros.append(contador);
}
lblTime.setText(numeros.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

No estás acumulando el resultado.

Debería ser algo así :

```
String resultado = "" ;
for(int contador = 0;contador <=10;contador++)
    resultado += String.valueOf(contador);

lblTime.setText(resultado);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int contador = 0;contador <=10;contador++)
lblTime.setText(lblTime.getText()+contador);
```

Con esto debería de quedar.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar una descripción que le explique al autor por qué esto soluciona su problema?